# mapDispatchToProps with typescript is being difficult

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Trying to build a simple react crud app with typescript and redux and ran in to the following issue. I have a function that has the specified signature that it will take a person object as an argument as seen here.

```
export default function savePerson(person: Person) {
    return async (dispatch: any) => {
        let newPerson = await axios.post('/api/people/addPeron', person);
        dispatch(addPersonSuccess(person));
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to connnect my component to redux I am having trouble with the `mapDispatchToProps`. Here is my code.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
  const actions = {
    savePerson: () => dispatch(savePerson())
  }
  return actions;
}
```

The issue is that the savePerson function requires a person to be passed to it, however I do not have access to my state in the `mapDispatchToProps`, and since the function is missing arguments my code wont compile. Any ideas?

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

Here is the code with the one change needed to make this code work.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
  const actions = {
    savePerson: (person: Person) => dispatch(savePerson(person))
  }
  return actions;
}
```

I just had to pass the person object to my anonymous function that is calling `dispatch`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import { AnyAction } from "redux";
import { ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
import { savePerson } from "../myActions";

// IExtraDispatchArguments usually is empty
import { IExtraDispatchArguments, IStoreState } from "../myGlobalTypes"

interface IMyComponentProps {
    savePerson: (person: Person) => Promise<void>;
}
class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMyComponentProps, void>{
    someMethod(person: Person) {
        this.actions.savePerson(person);
    }
}

const WrappedComponent = connect(
   (state: IStoreState, ownProps: {}) => ({
       // here you can map state
   }),
   (dispatch: (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<IStoreState, IExtraDispatchArguments, AnyAction>)) => ({
      // savePerson: (person: Person) => dispatch(savePerson(person))
      actions: {
         savePerson: (person: Person) => dispatch(savePerson(person))
      }
   }
);
```

Comment: The main take away that I got from your answer was the I did not pass the person object to my anonymous function that was calling dispatch, once I did that it worked. Accepting this answer now.

Comment: Informative, thanks. I am wondering if `dispatch` always returns a promise.

Comment: Informative, thanks. I am wondering if `dispatch` always returns a promise.

Comment: In my case defining dispatch as a type of `Dispatch<IStoreState>` throws this exception: `Property 'type' is missing in type 'IStoreState'`. (I'm using react 16.3.16)

Comment: @tudor, thank you for attention, I updated the answer.